# zend framework phpunit proper way to bootstrap

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit, bootstrapping

I am calling

```
$this->application->bootstrap()->run();
```

from inside my test setup function, and there is no output.  Are you supposed to call `run()` in the test environment?

My tests worked, but the front controller plugins never executed (which is necessary for my application).  Putting `->run()` executes the plugins, but the phpunit just stops and has no output.

I have working tests, but I need front controller plugins to execute in test environment.  Bootstrap executes, but plugins do not.  When they do via `->run()`, no output comes

Any suggestions?

EDIT: added `setup()` example

```
require_once realpath(__DIR__.'/../../').'/TestBackendConfiguration.php';

abstract class Controllers_Backend_BaseControllerTest extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase {

    protected $config;
    protected $application;
    protected $users;
    protected static $iterations = 0;

    public function setUp() {
        $this->bootstrap = array($this, 'appBootstrap');
        parent::setUp();
        $this->configureUsers();
        $this->configureACL($this->users);
    }

    public function appBootstrap() {
        $this->config = new Zend_Config_Ini(CORE_PATH . '/configs/common.ini', APPLICATION_ENV, true);
        $this->config->merge(new Zend_Config_Ini(CORE_PATH . '/configs/backend.ini', APPLICATION_ENV));
        $this->config->merge(new Zend_Config_Ini(CORE_PATH . '/configs/application.ini', APPLICATION_ENV));

        // Reset bootstraps
        $this->config->bootstrap->path = CORE_PATH . '/backend/Bootstrap.php';
        $this->config->resources->frontController->controllerDirectory = CORE_PATH . '/backend/controllers';
        $this->config->resources->frontController->actionHelperPaths->Frontend_Controller_Action_Helper = CORE_PATH . '/backend/controllers/Action/Helper';
        $this->config->resources->frontController->baseUrl = "/admin";
        $this->config->resources->layout->layoutPath = CORE_PATH . '/backend/layouts/scripts';


        $this->application = new Zend_Application( APPLICATION_ENV, $this->config );

        $this->application->bootstrap()->run(); 
     }
}
```

The reason for the tweaks to `$this->config` is because I have frontend and backend related tests, and they require different configs.  They have their own `Configuration.php` scripts which both declare `APPLICATION_PATH`, and thus which ever test runs 2nd can't redefine this const and the application doesn't bootstrap properly.

Right now, my main concern is that my plugins aren't dispatched in the test environment, and this breaks my application a bit because I have data added to the registry which I need access to and it's obviously not there.  Ideas?

Adding the `->run()` dispatches the plugins but no output for my tests. My backend controller tests all extend this class which is responsible for setting up the backend test environment.

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to call run(). Does your test class extend `Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase`? Can you post the whole setup method?

Comment: Sure, and yes, the test class extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase.  I have a base class which has the setup functionality, and then my individual controller tests are extending this class.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar problems lately, and finally found the solution. I hope it will be useful for someone.

The issue with resources in testing environment is that bootstrap object is assigned as a FrontController param in method `Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap::run()`, but this method is never executed in testing environment. That is the reason for the error while getting any resources via bootstrap (I assume you use `Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap')` somewhere in your code).

The workaround that helped me was to manually set the bootstrap param to FrontController in unit test like this:

```
public function setUp() {
    $this->bootstrap = array($this, 'appBootstrap');
    parent::setUp();
}

public function appBootstrap()
{
    $this->application = new Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV, APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini');
    $this->application->bootstrap();
    // set bootstrap param
    $bootstrap = $this->application->getBootstrap();
    $front = $bootstrap->getResource('FrontController');
    $front->setParam('bootstrap', $bootstrap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The setup method shouldn't actually bootstrap the application, just create the class to allow the tests to do that. So I think all you need to do is remove this line:

```
$this->application->bootstrap()->run();
```

Just to be safe I'd also move the `parent::setUp();` line in your setup method so it is called at the end of the function (after your two config methods). If those methods rely on the bootstrap being there then move them to the `appBootstrap` function instead.

Comment: Ok, plugins are now working and the order of execution is proper (plugins are being called). Thank you for that.

I'm now facing two issues...My models complain
Zend_Db_Table_Exception: No adapter found 

And the tests complain
Zend_Controller_Exception: No default module defined for this application

Are these bootstrapping issues?